# $N/F$ is finite galois. $E/F,L/F$ galois and $E,F\subset N$. Then $E\otimes_F L$ is a product of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory

$N/F$ is finite galois. $E/F,L/F$ galois and $E,F\subset N$. Then $E\otimes_F L\cong\prod_i EL$ where $i\in I$ with $|I|=\frac{G(N/F)}{G(N/E)G(N/F)}$.

Since $E/F,L/F$ are galois, $G(N/E),G(N/F)$ are normal subgroups of $G(N/F)$.

I can finish the proof easily by directly using simple extension argument. $E=\frac{F[x]}{(f)}=F(a)$ and $L=\frac{F[y]}{g}$. So $E\otimes_F L\cong F(a)\otimes_F\frac{F[x]}{g}\cong\frac{F(a)[y]}{(g)}$. Now from galois correspondence, $g$'s factor will split into product of degree $[L:E\cap L]$ polynomials. Now $G(N/E)G(N/L)$ fixes $E\cap L$. So $|\frac{G(N/F)}{G(N/E)G(N/F)}|$ counts exactly how many irreducible factors $g$ will have in $F(a)[y]$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ I am trying a different proof by group ring method. Let $G_1=G(E/F), G_2=G(L/F)$. $E\cong F[G_1]$ as $F[G_1]$ module but this is also $F$ module isomorphism by $F[G_1]$ linearity. Similarly $L\cong F[G_2]$. So $E\otimes_FL\cong F[G_1]\otimes_FF[G_2]\cong F[G_1\times G_2]$. $F[G(EL/F)]\cong EL$ as $EL/F$ is galois. Now $G(EL/F)\to G_1\times G_2$ is injection. I want to write $G(EL/F)$'s coset in $G_1\times G_2$. However, I cannot directly see correspondence with $\prod_{gG(N/E)G(N/L)}EL$. I want to follow this path. Hint will be sufficient.

Ref: Taylor Frolich Algebraic Number Theory Exercise Chpt 1.2

Comment: You're asking about $E\otimes_F L$ which seems to have nothing to do with $N$. For instance, $L$ is not assumed to be a subfield of $N$. And yet the right side of your isomorphism for $E\otimes_F L$ doesn't have $L$ in it? And the fraction for $I$ has $G(N/F)$ in both the numerator and denominator. Does your statement of the problem contain typos? Also, presumably the desired isomorphism is true as $F$-algebras, but $E\cong F[G_1]$ and $L\cong F[G_2]$ are only true as modules over $F[G_1]$ and $F[G_2]$ (respectively), so they won't translate into $F$-algebra isomorphisms will they?

Comment: @anon I think the statement is correct in that the galois translation theorem works here. If you choose $N=EL$ with $F=E\cap L$, then there is exactly 1 by assuming $E,F$ are linearly disjoint. The bijection is set theoretical first. Since $F[G_i]$ module structure can be endowed, it can be restricted to $F$ linear structure. This follows from normal basis theorem as $E/F$ is galois. The normal basis gives a vector space isomorphism over $F$. I think they do translate into $F-$module isomorphism. As $F-$algebra morphism, I am not sure at the moment. I think it might be the problem.

Comment: (1) You can pick $L$ to be anything Galois over $F$ and it changes the isomorphism class of the algebra $E\otimes_F L$, it even changes the dimension, but the right side of your isomorphism *doesn't depend on* $L$ so it must be wrong. And why write $EF$ when $EF$ is really just $E$, since $F\subset E$? And why write a complicated formula for $|I|$ if $I$ really is just $1$? (This follows from $G(N/F)$ being in both numerator and denominator of your formula for $|I|$.)

Comment: (2) You're talking about an $F$-module isomorphism, but that obviously follows from $F[G]$-module isomorphisms which I'm not talking about. I said, presumably the desired isomorphism is as $F$-*algebras*, and that's much stronger than a vector space isomorphism.

Comment: @anon (1) Sorry for the confusion. $EF$ should be $EL$ for composite field. There is no reason to consider $EF$. (2)$F-$algebra part is unclear. However, I think $F[G_1]\cong E$ is just $F-$module isomorphism once you choose the normal basis as this fixes representation of every element of $E$ by $\forall x\in E, x=\sum_if_i\sigma_i(a)$ for some $a\in E$. I do not think it has a compatible $F-$algebra structure to maintain the isomorphism. If I have $x=\sum f_i\sigma_i(a),y=\sum g_i\sigma_i(a)\in E$, $xy\in E$ but corresponding element in $F[G_1]$ is $\sum f_i\sigma_i\circ\sum g_j\sigma_j$.